# Sharing Android Phone's WiFi connection with OSX

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, android, bluetooth

Is it possible to tell OSX to connect to an Android phone (Sony Xperia Z2) via BlueTooth / USB and use the WiFi connection that's setup on the Android phone?

I've tried to setup [Bluetooth PAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_area_network#Bluetooth) on the phone seeing as OSX can connect to a Bluetooth PAN, but the phone doesn't seem to support Bluetooth PAN.

My friend has access to the WiFi via his phone, his roommate set it up for him, but he's away for a few months. I've tried plugin a cable into the router, but there seems to be Mac filtering setup on the router - so the only way I can connect to the WiFi is via his phone unless I know the WiFi password, which I don't.

Comment: At least for my ubuntu laptop, I just connect my phone to wifi, and then enable USB tethering.

Comment: Got it working, tethering was the right word, will post my answer shortly. Thanks David!

Answer (score 2):

First things first, enable bluetooth on your phone, pair it with OSX.

Now on the phone (this is on Android Lollipop), go to 
`Settings -> Wireless & networks -> More -> Tethering & portable hotspot -> enable Bluetooth tethering`.

[image]

On OSX, create a new Bluetooth PAN, you will be presented with the device you paired earlier

[image]

Then whatever means the phone is using to connect to the internet, in this case WiFi, will be shared to your Laptop.